# Accessing lineage of a NiFi flow file

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, nifi-api

I'm developing some kind of error handling for flow files for NiFi, e.g. a database sub-system refuses to write the data from a flow file, because the data is not as expected, because the source system of this data is missing some master data.
So this error handling writes the data into a MongoDB with more information what went wrong.
One of those 'more information' is some kind of stacktrace for this flow file, meaning the data lineage. For this purpose I wrote an InvokeScriptedProcessor with a Groovy script to achieve this.

Here is the important part of the script:

```
ArrayList getStacktrace(flowfileUuid){
    def lineage = this.provenanceRepository.createLineageQuery(flowfileUuid)
    def lineageData = this.provenanceRepository.getLineageData(lineage.id)

    if (lineageData.results == null || lineageData.results.nodes.size() == 0){
        println "cannot find stacktrace for ${flowfileUuid}."
        return []
    }
    def eventIds = lineageData.results.nodes.findAll {n -> n.type == 'EVENT'}.collect {n -> n.id }.sort()
    def provenanceEvents = []
    for (eventId in eventIds){
        provenanceEvents << this.provenanceRepository.getProvenanceEvent(eventId).provenanceEvent.componentName
    }
    this.provenanceRepository.deleteLineageQuery(lineage.id)
    return provenanceEvents
}
```

For `createLineageQuery` I'm `POSTING` to the nifi-api with `/nifi-api/provenance/lineage` adding the `uuid` of the flow file in the body. The result is, among others, the `ID` of the query. I'm using this `ID` to `getLineageData`; there is also a property `finished` and I'm waiting until the query is finished.
With this lineage data I `getProvenanceEvent` data and write the name of the component (processor) into an array.
After that I `deleteLineageQuery` as stated in the documentation.

So this would be my stack trace.

The problem now is, the the lineage data is empty when the flow file first hits this `InvokeScriptedProcessor`. I tried a lot of things, like waiting and stuff. Doesn't help.
Now the odd thing is, that the lineage data is not empty, when I replay the flow file for this processor.
So the behavior is not deterministic as I'm expecting it.
Sometimes the lineage data is not empty when I'm processing the flow file for the first time.
I also tried the thing with Fiddler, there it worked all the time.

Is there a problem with my approach?
I'm currently using `NiFi 1.6.0`.

**EDIT:**
I'll take the answer of Bryan as solution.
I'll investigate that as soon as I've got the time, but sounds correct. Nevertheless, I tried my solution with `NiFi 1.8.0` and it works as intended. So currently I'm fine with the way I implemented it in the first step, but I'll improve my solution with Bryan's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what the problem is, but in general provenance data is not really meant to be accessed from a processor, which is why there is no API provided by the session or context that lets you retrieve provenance events, only creating events is allowed.

In order to run a provenance query the events need to be indexed, and there is no guarantees about when the indexing will take place related to when the flow file is being processed. So it is possible the events are not visible yet.

A ReportingTask is the intended way to access provenance events and can be used to push them out of NiFi to some external system for longer term storage.

Comment: Actually I'm only using the nifi-api, thus it is only a normal API call; I also tried the same stuff with InvokeHTTP processors. Do you have an example for the ReportingTask? Might be not the correct solution for my problem, because I don't need the information all the time, only if a flow file runs into a failure queue.

Comment: Yes but if I'm understanding correctly, you are in a processor (InvokeScriptedProcessor) and then making a call to the NiFi REST API, and at that point there is no guarantee the provenance events have been indexed yet

Comment: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-bundle/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-task/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/reporting/SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask.java